# How to display enum getter value on view in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, enums, thymeleaf

I have an enum like this:

```
public enum UnitTypes {

LITER("l"), KILO("kg"), PIECE("pc");

private String unitType;

UnitTypes(String type) {
    this.unitType = unitType;
}

String getType() {
    return unitType;
}
```

}

How to display a single value from the getType method on view?

I try this, but it doesn't work:

```
<td th:text="${stock.unit.getType()}"></td>
```

In "stock" i have field, which is this enum type("unit")

Comment: What you have is correct (you could even put `${stock.unit.type}` to shorten it).  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Metroids Ok, I've changed getType() to public method. Now i don't have an error, but just a blank field(nothing is being displayed using this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UnitTypes(String type) {
    this.unitType = unitType;
}
```

This code should be

```
UnitTypes(String type) {
    this.unitType = type;
}
```

You are assigning unitType to itself, in your original code.